# Setting column width in Data grid view for my table

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am getting a error when I am trying to get a specific column from my table in the datagridview.

Here is how I populate the table----

```
public DataTable createGridForForm(int rows, int columns)
        {

            // Create the output table.
            DataTable table = new DataTable();


                   for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
            {
                table.Columns.Add("column " + i.ToString());
            }


            for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
                // populate data row with values here
                table.Rows.Add(dr);
            }    

            return table;
        }
```

And here is how i create the datagridview------

```
private void createGridInForm(int rows, int columns)
        {

            DataGridView RunTimeCreatedDataGridView = new DataGridView();
            RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.DataSource = createGridForForm(rows, columns);
            DataGridViewColumn ID_Column = RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Columns[0];
        ID_Column.Width = 200;

            int positionForTable = getLocationForTable();
            RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Size = new Size(800, 200);
            RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Location = new Point(5, positionForTable);
            myTabPage.Controls.Add(RunTimeCreatedDataGridView);

        }
```

The error I am getting is that the Index was out of range. It may not be negative and must be smaller than the size. What I am trying to do is that I'm getting a table from a text file and then in run time I am showing it in my form, but the table doesn't match my data grid view in size, it doesn't look good. So I want to make the table fit the Data grid view.

Comment: If column 0 is out of range, then the DGV must be empty, which means the DataTable must be returning nothing.  I would add some break points in your createGridForForm method to check what's going on.  For instance, if you called createGridForForm(1,1), one column would be added but zero rows would be added.

Answer (score 0):

Try-

```
DataGridViewColumn ID_Column = dataGridView1.Columns[0];
ID_Column.Width = 200;
```

Comment: no it doesn't work :(. the error is the same ----An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll